# How to use payment function to pay users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action

Excuse for this, but I can't debug in development mode, because of problems with SSL certificate.

So I deployed my application to Heroku.

**I will change into real credentiails later.**

I have action in MerchantsController:

```
class MerchantsController < ApplicationController
 helper_method :send_money

 def send_money(to_email, how_much_in_cents, options = {})
credentials = {
  "USER" => 'pro._1342094044_biz_api1.gmail.com',
  "PWD" => '1342094095',
  "SIGNATURE" => 'AMVxTgrWf6tUTF0Rf0y4QsqTFFAcApSXcqINQj2b2-a5wFhIx3UG87E- ',
}

params = {
  "METHOD" => "MassPay",
  "CURRENCYCODE" => "USD",
  "RECEIVERTYPE" => "EmailAddress",
  "L_EMAIL0" => to_email,
  "L_AMT0" => ((how_much_in_cents.to_i)/100.to_f).to_s,
  "VERSION" => "51.0"
}
  endpoint = ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == 'production' ? "https://api-3t.paypal.com" : "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com"
url = URI.parse(endpoint)
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
all_params = credentials.merge(params)
stringified_params = all_params.collect { |tuple| "#{tuple.first}={CGI.escape(tuple.last)}" }.join("&")
response = http.post("/nvp", stringified_params)
 end
```

I added route:

```
      match 'merchants/send_money' => 'merchants#send_money', :via => [ :post ]
```

Now, how I can call it, because this is wrong(from views):

```
        <%=  link_to "Pay", merchants_send_money_path('pro_1342434702_biz@gmail.com',1) %>
```

Heroku logs:

```
   ←[35m2012-07-16T18:02:02+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass)
```

How I should make this right ?

Comment: have you considered using activemerchant? some links: http://activemerchant.org/ Old rails cast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/144-active-merchant-basics/ All paypal railscasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=paypal

Comment: house9, do you think it is better ? I want to make payment function without confirmation or it is impossible ?

Comment: Didnt relize you were trying to send payment, i thought you were accpting payment, ignore my comment

Comment: house9, did you use NET::HTTP class ? Because I constantly get error with it.